# Возможно ли скачать сгенерированный docx файл отдаваемый php через js?

Tags: javascript, php, phpword

Делаю генерацию документов по шаблону. Шаблоны хранятся на яндекс.диске.

Php сначала подключается к яндекс.диску 
>
получает ссылку на шаблон 
>
отдает ее на обработку PhpOffice, который подставляет все нужное.

PHP выглядит так:

```
$curl = curl_init();
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/resources/download?path='.$path.'');
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
                            "Authorization: OAuth ".$IntegrationsService->secret_key.""
                        ]);
                    $content = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
                    //print_r($content->href);
                    curl_close($curl);

                        $_doc = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(''.$content->href.'');
                         //номер договора
                        // Данные для файла
                        $doc_data  = array(
                            array("label" => "d_num", "value" => "3132"),                   
                            array("label" => "d_date", "value" => "20/12/2010"),                    
                            array("label" => "last_name", "value" => "Тестеров"),                   
                            array("label" => "name", "value" => "Тестер"),                  
                            array("label" => "surname", "value" => "Тесторович"),                   

                        );

                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($doc_data); $i++) {

                            $_doc->setValue(''.$doc_data[$i]['label'].'', ''.$doc_data[$i]['value'].'');
                        }

                        // вывод непосредственно в браузер
                        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$file_name_after_generation.'.docx"');
                        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
                        $_doc->saveAs('php://output');

                    $json_output = array('success'=>1, 'path'=>''.$_doc->saveAs('php://output').'');
```

Если обращаться напрямую к файлу, то скачивается сгенеррированный, а если через JS, то ничего не происходит, точнее в консоли появляется в ответе это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

JS выглядит так:

```
$('body').on('click', '.file-action', function(){


    $.ajax({
            type: "get",
            url: "/php/t.php?q=PhpOffice",
            data: "", 
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function(){                  
            },
            success: function(data){

                if (data.success == 1) {

                        var link = document.createElement('a');
                        link.setAttribute('href',''+data.path+'');
                        link.setAttribute('download','46546');
                        link.click();

                }
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27701981/6138795

Comment: @СергейМишин что-то не сработало, почему-то при скачивании файла он с ошибкой. "Ошибка: Неполадка сервера"... Может путь не тот...

Comment: @СергейМишин поправил, забыл добавить data:

Comment: Когда сервер отвечает, что у него неполадки, очевидно надо искать проблему там. Включите отладчик и посмотрите что у вас там происходит

Answer (score 1):

Нужно еще одна атрибут для тега  которые ты создаешь.

```
link.setAttribute('target' , '_blank');
```